# I get (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2) in Flutter when file.delete(). At the same file.exist() return true

Tags: android, flutter, mobile

I am developing a Flutter app. I am trying to add a functionality to delete a file in device storage. When i initialize a file object with the path to the file, and run file.exist() i get true. But when i run file.delete() i get

```
(OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)when file.delete(). At the same file.exist() return true!
```

I have these permissions in my manifest

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_MEDIA_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STORAGE_INTERNAL" />
```

and

```
  <application
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

And i am using permission_handler to ask for permission first.

Any idea?

Comment: Use also File.canRead(). And use File.canWrite() before you try to delete.

Comment: @blackapps Thanks for your answer. I am using Flutter. File.canRead() is java method.

Comment: I'm facing same issue. could you solve it?

Comment: same issue with me .. fresh files working good .. old files cannot delete may be indexing issue

Comment: Same issue with delete file method in flutter.. any idea how resolve?